# execv not working for " execv("/bin/echo", ["echo","$PATH"] )?

Tags: c, unix

I am calling echo using execv with the argument : $PATH and the output is $PATH and not the actual value of the $PATH environment variable which is what I get when I do the same in bash.

Why is this happening? I am passing all the right arguments..

```
execv("/bin/echo", ["echo","$PATH"]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the actual code.

Comment: @KeithThompson it's in the title.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: No, it isn't; the code in the title is a syntax error.

Comment: @user1479589: What exactly do you find so amusing? If you'll update your question to show us the actual code you've written, it's easier to give meaningful answers.

Comment: The code is in the title..

Comment: @user1479589, I'd also like to ask you to post the code.  For example, I guess you might be using `{` instead of `[` to surround the list of args?  (Even this mightn't work, but it's a start). Using `{` and C++11, it is possible that line of code would be valid.  But as this is a C question, I don't see how your use of `[` could be valid.

Comment: @user1479589: No, the code is not in the title, nor is it in the body of the question. What's in the title is not syntactically correct C code. C does not have a `[ ... ]` syntax for array literals. Please copy and paste the actual code that you fed to the compiler.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: No, changing `[` to `{` won't help. C's compound literals (which were introduced in C99, not C11 -- and we're not even discussing C++) require a parenthesized type name. In any case, the OP clearly already has code that compiles, since he's describing its runtime behavior; he just needs to show it to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` interprets and expands expressions like `$PATH`, not the operating system. You pass to `execv` exactly the strings you want the programs to receive as arguments, literally, without quotes, escape characters, shell expansions, etc., etc.

Use `getenv` to look up the value of environment variables like `PATH`.

Comment: Also, do you know why cd also does not work in the same way e.g.:

execv(”/bin/cd“, [”cd“,”.."] )? or even a path for cd argument.. still does not work..

Comment: Because there is no `/bin/cd`. It couldn't work, because every process has its own working directory; when the process terminates, all that is history. Use the library function `chdir` to change the working directory of your process, but don't expect it to apply to the shell which calls your program.

Answer (score 1):

Bash changes $PATH to the value of the environmental variable PATH before sending the arguments to `cat`. However, `execv()` doesn't do that and so cat receives the literal string `$PATH` as an argument. To get the PATH environmental variable, pass "PATH" to [getenv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
echo $PATH
```

in a shell, it's your shell (`bash`, `csh`, `ksh`, ...) that performs the expansion of the environment variable `$PATH`, `echo` never actually sees `$PATH`, but gets already the expanded value on its command line.<sup>1</sup>

If you want to get the content of an environment variable from your C program, you have to use `getenv`:

```
const char *args[2]={"echo", getenv("PATH")};
execv("/bin/echo", args);
```

---

1. actually, usually shells don't call `/bin/echo`, but their builtin `echo` instruction, but this is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the string literal `"$PATH"` is just a 5-character string (6 including the terminating `'\0'`). There is no mechanism to expand reference to environment variables, as there is in bash.

If you want to expand the value of an environment variable, you can use the standard `getenv()` function: `getenv("PATH")`.

I'm not aware of any standard function that recognizes the `$VAR` syntax recognized by the shell.